# Change path of Exec wget

Tags: php, exec, wget

```
$get = exec("wget $url > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

I use above code to execute particular url in background. But all the dump URLs are getting saved in my root folder. How can change the folder? Or, if you give me code to auto delete dumps, it will be great.

Comment: Hmmm noobs always get -1 :D lol

Comment: I think @Madbreaks means this could be used for malicious purposes. Anyway, check `wget` options.

Comment: its not any malcious !! , It just running my own app url !! and it saves all dumps in my root folder :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hmmm noobs always get -1 :D lol – Sunita Shivnani 17 mins ago` because you should use look at documentation more often

[WGET DOC](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

> ‘-P prefix’ 
> ‘--directory-prefix=prefix’
> Set directory prefix to prefix. The directory prefix is the directory where all other
>       files and subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree. 
>       The default is ‘.’ (the current directory).

Example

```
$get = exec("wget -P /path/directory $url > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: thanks :) ,,, i googled it ,, i swear i did not good answer like this :) thank you so much